# proper preparation before upgrading jenkins

Tags: jenkins, upgrade

I'm going to upgrade our jenkins-ci to the latest version. I'm following this wiki page (Going for the upgrade button in the "Manage jenkins page"): [How to upgrade jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Automated+Upgrade)

My question is this, we have a lot of jobs that constantly run (some timed jobs, some triggered jobs). When upgrading, should (or even need) I disable all jobs before hand? If there are jobs currently running, should (or even need) i terminate them?

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot how you deployed you CI. If you installed by default (no custom settings i assume you can follow the auto procedure that you already provided in link).

> When upgrading, should (or even need) I disable all jobs before hand?

When upgrading you should put your Jenkins instance in the quiet mode `Configure > Manage > Quiet down`, this will prevent further builds to be executed, also it will let all running builds to finish, i hope this answer to your both questions.
Speaking more about jobs, you should make a backup first in case something goes wrong. 
Also you should think a lot about plugins and review them all since some of them might not work as you expect since you are upgrading to the new fresh Jenkins core. There is one plugin called [plugin usage](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugin+Usage+Plugin+%28Community%29) which might help you to understand your current status